# Potentially dumb question: Is there a way to update all headers and footers from a template?

Tags: html

I have a static HTML site hosted on github pages and I was wondering if there is any code that could use a template to fill in the header and footer of every page? I thought I remembered learning this a long time ago but don't know what to search. In my mind I'm picturing creating a header.html and a footer.html and just pulling from those files on each page...idk any help is appreciated!

Comment: I suspect you're remembering https://api.jquery.com/load/. A better option is using a static site generator like jekyll or hugo though.

Answer (score 0):

Github pages is also 'Jekyll'. You can create 'layouts' that can have common headers/footers and use them across pages. I'd recommend looking at some default Github pages templates to get an idea of how it works.